# Know when time has passed beyond a certain point, using Joda

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, jodatime

I'm developing an Android app which fetches time from a server, what I want to know is when that time has passed.

I'm currently trying this with the Joda java library to no success.

I've tried this:

```
public void countTime(){

    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    DateTime then = bus.getArrivalDateTime();

    int i = now.compareTo(then);
    Log.w(LOGTAG, "Difference " + i + " " + now.toString() + " "  + then.toString());
    if (i > 0) {
        Log.w(LOGTAG, "BEFORE");
    } else {
        Log.w(LOGTAG, "AFTER");
    }
}
```

But now.compareTo(then), always returns 1, even though the time has passed.
It does not matter if it's passed by 3 hours the compareTo still shows 1.

I've also tried the isBefore, and isBeforeNow, methods but can't get the right answer.
The log shows this at the moment:

```
Difference 1  2013-09-22T12:24:23.791+02:00   2013-01-22T12:11:48.000+01:00
```

Comment: Have you noticed that the two dates are not on the same time zone (+0200 vs +0100)?

Comment: Yey, but that is a separate problem from the one I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Yep. Accepted it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Period` difference with `PeriodType.hours()`

```
  DateTime da = new DateTime("2013-09-22T12:24:23.791+02:00");
  DateTime db = new DateTime("2013-01-22T12:11:48.000+01:00");

  Period difference = new Period(db, da, PeriodType.hours());

   int hour = difference.getHours();
```

Output:   `5831`

It will take care for different TZ as well

unitest Android with `joda-time-2.1`

Comment: This coud be used as a solution, but it is also a great way to debug. Thanks :)